# How to make objects stick to edges of minimap when they are offscreen in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi guys I am making a minimap for my game in unity. I have used two terrains and two cameras. One terrain is shown by main camera and other is shown by minimap camera. Now my problem is in my minimap,  I have to show target objects to boundary of minimap when they are outside the boundary of camera. I am not using canvas for showing minimap. I have searched internet but no success.

Comment: How your targets objects are displayed on the minimap ?

Comment: You'll have to do some math here I think : getting the boundaries of your minimap display and then raycasting/vector projecting your targets to those boundaries so they appear on the border of your minimap.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuV9Xlt-l6g. My targets will display like icons.

Comment: You should include the current implementation of your minimap. Like @Kardux said, you probably just need some math, like a min and max call somewhere in there.

Comment: Can you give me idea like how to stick icons to edges when target is not appearing in minimap and what kind of math work?